# Не работает web api на сервере .NetFramework 4.8

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

При обновлении проекта с платформы .NetFramework 4.5.2 на .NetFramework 4.8 происходит ошибка роутинга, post запрос возвращает error 404. Приложение развернуто на Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.0.
На локальной машине в VS проект работает без проблем.
После недельных танцев с бубном попробовал приложение Security вернуть на версию .NetFramework 4.5.2 и это сработало. Теперь роут отрабатывает коректно.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать в чем может быть проблема? Что такого происходит при смене платформы?

Дополняю:
Прикладываю структуру приложения на сервере. Само веб-приложение работает на .net4.8 не работает только security. Причем, если запускать в IIS приложение security то оно открывает стартовую страницу, а роут дальшене проходит.

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проекта]

web-application iis
[image: web-application iis]

web-application server
[image: web-application server]

application Security and exist
[image: application Security and exist]

Страница загрузки приложения Security
[image: Страница загрузки приложения Security]

Ошибка возникающая при авторизации
[image: Ошибка возникающая при авторизации]

Детальное описание ошибки
[image: Детальное описание ошибки]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5.2-4.8 скорее всего у вас это - Вызовы к конструкторам ClaimsIdentity

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Наткнулся на статью по миграции. Выполнив предложенный вариант ничего не изменилось. post метод аутентификации возвращает ошибку 500

Comment: почитайте эту статейку ещё, возможно что-то из неё подойдёт (там есть что-то и про роуты)

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Попробовал и внес правки указанные в гайде, но результат остался прежним. 
Решил попробовать обновить приложение security до netframework 4.6 и посмотреть, какой будет результат, но ошибка точно такая же. Также использовал гайд миграций и вносил изменения в конфиг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарии выше!

В общем проекту security необходимо работать под framework 4.5. Просто оставили одно приложение без изменения целевой платформы. По каким причинам не известно, но работа приложения в целом не страдает от использования разных целевых платформ в приложениях.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/750877)